# How can I make cookies less dry and crumbly?

Tags: baking, cookies, dry

I have made [these cookies](http://sugarcrafter.net/2011/11/03/vanilla-latte-cookies) once before. I stuck to the recipe and really liked the flavor, but found that they were very dry and crumbly. I would like to make them again with better results. Looking over the recipe, it seems like it does not have any ingredients that really bind it all together. I am wondering what I could add (and how much) to improve the texture of these cookies. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the forum!
Your recipe for Vanilla Latte cookies looks really yummy! However, confectionery sugar does make cookies crumble. I have actually moved away from cookie recipes with butter and margarine in them and depending on the type of cookie you want to make, you can now substitute oil for margarine/butter and keep the chewy, moist texture you probably are looking for. I don't have a recipe for the cookies you posted but I have a great chocolate chip cookie recipe I can share that has oil in it. One of the tricks to keep cookies chewy and not crumbly and hard is to underbake them by a couple of minutes. Cookies will continue to bake after they come out of the oven. So take them out a couple minutes before the recipe tells you to. Maybe that will even work with your recipe. Good luck and let me know if you want the recipe above.